# sendStickyBroadcast() does not really stick around

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, broadcastreceiver

I am currently working on a test application that will show a dialog that asks the user to stop using the app if he/she is driving. Supposing that the user has their GPS on, I have created a custom intent to be broadcast and then on the onReceive() method of the subclassed BroadcastReceiver class, the speed of the vehicle is calculated and if it's found to be in the range of usual car speeds, a dialog is shown to the user.

The second part (the onReceive() code) works great: the speed is calculated and the dialog is shown. However, I am at a loss about how the dialog can be shown at any point of the lifeycle of that specific activity. If the app is launched while the user is driving or if the user navigates to another activity and then back to the activity that does the speed check (essentially, if onCreate() or onResume() are called), the dialog is shown. If the dialog is dismissed and the user stays on the same activity, the dialog is not reshown, even if the user keeps driving (to be clear, the desired behavior is for the dialog to keep getting shown for as long as the user keeps driving and is in the activity). Here is the code of the activity that sends the Broadcast(the relevant code, everything else is omitted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    SpeedReceiver speedceiver = new SpeedReceiver();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        broadcastSender();

        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("com.example.animationshitz.ACTION_GET_SPEED");

            }
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();


        registerReceiver(speedceiver, intentFilter);
        Log.d("Loggger", "BROADCAST RECEIVER REGISTERED");

    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(speedceiver);
    }

    public void broadcastSender() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.animationshitz.ACTION_GET_SPEED");

        sendStickyBroadcast(intent);

        Log.d("Loggger", "BROADCAST SENT");
    }
}
```

Am I completely wrong about this? I thought that the sticky broadcast would keep calling the onReceive() method of the receiver so that it would keep checking the speed in the background. Is there some other way to achieve what I want? Maybe the onReceive() method should start a service that keeps checking the speed in the background? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: "I thought that the sticky broadcast would keep calling the onReceive() method of the receiver so that it would keep checking the speed in the background" -- no. It just arranges so that if something else calls `registerReceiver()` later for that broadcast, it will immediately be handed the last sticky broadcast.

Comment: I was just going through Busy Coder's to find an answer to this :)

Comment: @CommonsWare i keep on receiving onReceive method since i m registering CONNECTIVITY_ACTION dynamically ...i wanna know who calls it android? and who remove it in android framework..